# How to use selected WP function in custom PHP file?

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom PHP file on which I want to use some WordPress functions such as *wp_get_current_user()*. I've tried requiring *wp-load.php*, but that increases the load time significantly as it loads all WP functions.

Is there anyway I can use only the functions I need from WP?

Thanks, Emir

Comment: If you want to use the framework, you have to load the framework. Most 'front-end' functions are abstractions of other, deeper functions, so you can't cherry-pick what you need, as they rely on everything else being there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create page template or plugin then you able to access wp_get_currunt_user() function in you template file or plugin file

Comment: Hi Balwinder, thanks for helping out. The PHP file that I'm using is a non-WordPress file, it's used to query data server side so I cannot create it as a page template. Is there any other way?